email Automation to new ADO Work Item with custom message
I Have a question regarding ADO Work item
If a new bug is added to particular team, Can we send an automated email to specific team distro with custom message? So that the whole users under that distro can get notified as a new bug was added?
Thanks.
If a new bug is added to particular team, Can we send an automated email to specific team distro with custom message? So that the whole users under that distro can get notified as a new bug was added?
